# How to dynamically change content of web page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I don't know if this is a PHP or JavaScript code, but what do you call this technique about changing web content? For an instance, the [MDC Web](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog) demo site. It has an empty content if you view the source, but completely contains all elements if you inspect the page.

Regarding PHP, I think it is done with a PHP code in MDC Web's case, but how exactly? Is this a common technique? I wanna know this method coz it's useful in some cases where there's actually no need to reload the page, but able to change the content and URL.

Comment: PHP is server-side only. Dynamic client-side changes is called DOM manipulation, done through Javascript.

Comment: @CertainPerformance If that's the case, AJAX can be used right? But how about the URL? The URL changes along with the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called Single Page Applications (a.k.a SPA).

> A single-page application (SPA) is a web application or web site that interacts with the user by dynamically rewriting the current page rather than loading entire new pages from a server. This approach avoids interruption of the user experience between successive pages, making the application behave more like a desktop application [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).